# Are Google Docs secure for financial information?

Tags: security

I am dealing with a vendor who needs to pay me. They provided a Google Doc where I can enter my bank routing # or credit card #. Would this be secure?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about cyber security and not personal finance. Also, it's a question of opinion, not really answerable with a factual statement.

Comment: In general, neither your bank routing number nor your credit card number are secret. Bank routing numbers are published by the banks, and you give your credit card number everywhere you use it.

Comment: Is that *all* they are asking for?

Comment: Depending on how the doc is configured it may or may not be more secure than emailing them the information.

Comment: If they are going to pay you, why do they want your credit card number?

Comment: VERY good point, @mhoran_psprep. Beware scam!

Comment: @littleadv, if it makes sense to close the question, that's fine.
I appreciate the validation that this method was little weird and had them send me a check instead.